# didnt destroyed the page after change the route on nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lifecycle

I have a simple page on my page I have a function that calls the api. This function did not disappear when I changed the page and it calls the api method again

myFunction

```js
async getFlights() {
  try {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get(
      `/api/v1/flights/${this.flightIndexResponse.index}`,
    );
    this.filterResult = [];
    this.loadingFlights = false;
    this.flightResponse = data?.data?.items;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e?.response?.data?.code === 418 && this.teapotErrorCounter < 10) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.getFlights();
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      this.reponseStatus = false;
      this.flightResponse = [];
      this.reponseStatus = false;
      this.loadingFlights = false;
    }
  }
}
```

when server response with status code 418 . this function run again . and when I change the route did'nt destroy the function

Comment: More context would be quite helpful here. Is it in a `layout`, `middleware`? What do you mean by `This function did not disappear`?

Comment: this function called on the page and I mean this function did'nt destroyed after changed the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function adds a callback execution to a distinct queue for the process to execute later.
So even if you change the page and the component gets destroyed, the `setTimeout` callback is still there (all the code is still loaded, it's just the Vue component instance that is gone)

Several possible solutions here but I'd advise you to cancel the setTimeout on page change.

`vue-router` exposes several hooks (called [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)) to listen on page changes:

```js
retryTimeout: null,

[...]

if (e?.response?.data?.code === 418 && this.teapotErrorCounter < 10) {
  this.retryTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     this.getFlights();
  }, 2000);
}

[...]

beforeRouteLeave() {
  // when leaving the page
  clearTimeout(this.retryTimeout)
}
```

Comment: Oh right, missed out the `setTimeout`. Nice catch. @amir Overall, just don't use that to manage any thing really, especially if you call the function inside again.